# Scheduler with AWS Lambda API Proxy

Tags: aws-lambda

I am using the AWS Lambda with ServerLess framework to build Scheduler Application + API using .net core.

I have created one Web API Controller and a method which does the transaction process and returns the result. When I am accessing my method with an API end point everything is working fine.

Now I want to set the scheduler for the same method so that it will execute every 5 hours.
I have added following line in my `serverless.yml` file:

```
functions:
  mvc:
    handler: TestApplication::TestApplication.src.Infrastructure.EntryPoints.LambdaMvcEntryPoint::FunctionHandlerAsync
    events:
      - http:
          path: "/{proxy+}"
          method: "ANY"
```

Does anyone have an idea how to set the scheduler with proxy API case?

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read the [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I reformulated the question and formatted the code section.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that in your `serverless.yml` by adding a `schedule` in your events.

Documentation: https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/schedule/

Basically, your `serverless.yml` will look like this...

```
functions:
  mvc:
    handler: TestApplication::TestApplication.src.Infrastructure.EntryPoints.LambdaMvcEntryPoint::FunctionHandlerAsync
    events:
      - http:
          path: "/{proxy+}"
          method: "ANY"
      - schedule:
          rate: rate(5 hours)
          enabled: true
```

Answer (score 0):

In your scenario, You can set the expression in AWS cloudwatch and point your lambda function to that cloudwatch.

Go to AWS console -> click on lambda function -> Click on trigger ->Add Trigger ->choose aws cloudwatch  -> set expression

Comment: Thanks for your reply. We do not have access of AWS console. We need to manage it only from serverless.yml file.